# Why does FFTW3 with single precision and `--enable-neon` producing incorrect results?

Tags: c++, signal-processing, fft, fftw, dft

I am testing 1D Discrete Fourier Transform (DFT) for freq captures for a certain freq range and using `fftwf` with neon as compared to double precision `fftw_` running on the CPU and get inconsistent results

fftw version 3.3.10 on a armv8 processor with cortex-a53

FFTW with neon enabled is compiled using the following configure flags :
 `--enable-single --enable-shared --enable-neon --with-slow-timer` and the binary is linked against `libfftw3f.so`

FFTW without neon is compiles using default compiler flags and binary is linked against `libfftw3.so`

Since the dataset is fairly large I am only including some values to show the difference

| Idx | FFTW double precision without neon output | FFTW single precision with neon output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | "(411.000000,-1970.000000)" | "(-24346022117376.000000,3996000981822.062500)" |
| 1 | "(6.699506,157.978528)" | "(-70605390341.094666,15739685789749.212891)" |
| 2 | "(-1061.360551,223.266681)" | "(3019293206.230324,-8422263838.220203)" |
| 3 | "(-395.122847,458.200142)" | "(208581002563.746704,-458609832007096.500000)" |
| 4 | "(-809.101872,-15.506940)" | "(2339740602602.334961,-8443388804308.250000)" |
| 5 | "(-304.823606,200.779641)" | "(-678.664189,-252575116024967.750000)" |
| 6 | "(214.473359,142.314081)" | "(-339049665.096514,-3947957340133.003418)" |
| 7 | "(-459.241410,180.854491)" | "(8001465388.475181,48879919458.499710)" |
| 8 | "(-419.022648,423.454902)" | "(-10216871992.858559,-32842772072564.468750)" |
| 9 | "(-661.825512,493.852372)" | "(-17323006187007.830078,1736369122692691.000000)" |
| 10 | "(-415.154668,536.509157)" | "(-56738909008774.687500,42.718758)" |
| 8184 | "(-587.599598,-171.811375)" | "(0.000000,0.000000)" |
| 8185 | "(-288.930391,100.620046)" | "(0.000000,0.000000)" |
| 8186 | "(-852.919184,371.910236)" | "(0.000000,0.000000)" |
| 8187 | "(-26.188756,200.948488)" | "(0.000000,0.000000)" |
| 8188 | "(-274.017307,-45.880685)" | "(0.000000,0.000000)" |
| 8189 | "(-280.787270,50.315612)" | "(0.000000,0.000000)" |
| 8190 | "(-225.151149,-387.219741)" | "(0.000000,0.000000)" |
| 8191 | "(-733.685217,-155.193636)" | "(0.000000,0.000000)" |

With single precision the values at and past 4096 are all (0,0)

Input and output vector generation:

```
std::vector<std::complex<double>> input_raw_capture = getRawData(); //Fetches raw data from HW
// input_raw_capture size is 32000 after the previous step

constexpr unsigned int size_of_fft = std::pow(2,13); //8192
std::vector<std::complex<double>> output_fft_data;
output_fft_data.resize(input_raw_capture.size(), std::vector<std::complex<double>> (size_of_fft, 0));
```

Single precision neon binary code

```
//For single precision fftw with neon
fftwf_plan my_plan = fftwf_plan_dft_1d(size_of_fft,
                                reinterpret_cast<fftwf_complex *>((input_raw_capture).data()),
                                reinterpret_cast<fftwf_complex *>((output_fft_data).data()),
                                FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
fftwf_execute(my_plan);
fftwf_destroy_plan(my_plan);
```

Double precision code

```
//For double precision without neon
fftw_plan my_plan2 = fftw_plan_dft_1d(size_of_fft,
                                reinterpret_cast<fftw_complex *>((input_raw_capture).data()),
                                reinterpret_cast<fftw_complex *>((output_fft_data).data()),
                                FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
fftw_execute(my_plan2);
fftw_destroy_plan(my_plan2);
```

The raw data is 32000 size vector of `std::complex<double>` , few samples are included here:

| Raw Data |
| --- |
| (-862,-102) |
| (-576,-271) |
| (-299,-439) |
| (-64,-551) |
| (89,-542) |
| (136,-417) |
| (60,-195) |
| (-154,70) |
| (-475,325) |
| (-811,452) |
| (-980,390) |
| (-891,127) |
| (-506,-256) |
| (18,-582) |
| ..... |

Has anyone noticed this issue before ?

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre]. Reduce the signal size to the smallest power of two that reproduces the problem, and replace the data with the simplest signal that reproduces the problem (e.g., all zeros, all zeros except a 1 in the 0 subscript position all zeros except a 1 in the 1 subscription position, et cetera). The linearity of the FFT means you can almost always find a simple signal that demonstrates a problem (and hence that gives clues to the nature of the problem).

Comment: Does the single-precision FFTW without NEON produce correct results?

Comment: Do you expect `reinterpret_cast<fftwf_complex *>((input_raw_capture).data())` to convert the double-precision data in `input_raw_capture` to single-precision?

Comment: It does not
Single precision with or without neon produces incorrect result

Comment: @EricPostpischil I cannot change the HW output code therefore am stuck with `reinterpret_cast` for changing std::complex<double>* to fftwf_complex*

Comment: Do not use `size_of_fft = std::pow(2,13)`. Some `pow` implementations do not produce exact results for this case. Use `1 << 13`.

Comment: Since incorrect data is produced with or without NEON, it appears the trigger is single-precision, not NEON. So you should edit the title to remove reference to NEON.

Comment: A `reinterpret_cast` will not change the data from double-precision to single-precision. You must construct a new array of single-precision and assign data from the original double-precision array into the new single-precision array.